# iOS 7 Activation Error (legal)

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore, ios

I was on the iOS 7 beta in it's entirety and updated to the public version via my phone. Last night I got an activation error which is incorrect as I work for a company that builds apps and we even published 3 apps for the iOS 7 release.

So WHY is my phone bricked? I have SMS data since my last backup that I ***do not want to lose***. I've tried a number of things to try and get my phone to it's non-bricked self and nothing is helping so far. Out of all the things I've tried, below is the closest to a solution:

## Closest Solution

I retrieved the iOS 7.0.2 ISPW from the Member Developer center and installed it onto my phone. This *still* wants me to recover from a backup so I found a way to backup my phone after 7.0.2 installed as I could not back it up before. Now whenever I backup to that version I'm presented with the welcome screen and prompted to restore from a backup.

Comment: possibly related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104381/your-iphone-could-not-be-activated-because-the-activation-server-is-temporarily

Comment: Whilst your latest iTunes backup might not be the most recent backup, do you use iCloud Backup since you could restore from that backup instead? Also, you mentioned that you *installed* iOS 7.0.2 - did you ⌥-update or ⌥-restore through iTunes? The former *should* have preserved your information, whilst the latter will have deleted everything on your phone leaving you at the restore from backup screen. If you have performed the latter, there is currently no way to recover data from a restored iPhone without the use of a backup (whether that be from iTunes or iCloud Backup).

Comment: I did ⌥-restore so it sounds like I'm SOL then. I really got the bad end of this deal as I just lost 3 months worth of photos and messages. Lessons learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue this morning, it's because the beta has expired. You shouldn't need to restore, you can just update to the latest firmware (this will leave all your photos/messages/apps etc as they are):

1. Download the latest .ipsw for your device from http://developer.apple.com/.
2. Update to the latest version of iTunes.
3. Plug your phone into your computer and select it from the devices on the left in iTunes.
4. Alt-click on "Check for Update" button and choose the downloaded .ipsw.

Comment: I'm learning now that I'm hosed but this is technically the correct answer.